# Which Schema.org hierarchy should I use for my page?

Tags: seo, schema.org, html5

I have a website with all handy tools, for example, Random Word Generator, Separate a list, etc. Now I want to boost my SEO and one of the things I want to add is Schema.org markup. So I've taken a look at the Schema.org Full Hierarchy and what should I use? Tool? Instrument? HowToTool? Here is the [html5 code](https://pastecode.xyz/view/d4d510ab) for one of my pages and a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL2Hd.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication. You must add a price though (i.e. "free" if no price), otherwise, you will annoy Google. Personally, I would take the example that Google gives here: [google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/software-app) as a template and fill in with your own info. Always check Googles "Guidelines" for what is "required". Then test it here: [Google testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/)